# Is this limit meaningless or meaningful $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} n }{\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2 }\right] ?$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know,

$$\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} n }{\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2 }=\text{undefined}$$

But, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n^2}=0$$

Then, I want to ask, is this limit meaningless or meaningful?

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} n }{\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2 }\right]$$

Comment: Meaningless.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Where did the expression come from? Please provide some context as part of your post.

Comment: So if you know the inner fraction is undefined, why would you ask the question?

Comment: How can you expect the outer limit to make sense given that the inner expression is undefined?

Comment: You still haven't indicated where the problem comes from. Is it something you saw? If so, where? Is it part of an attempt by you to solve some other problem? If so, show the other problem.

Comment: The first and last expressions are equal to $1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n^2} $$
which is $0$.

But it becomes nonsense (or very close to it) when you have one $\lim\limits_{n\to \cdots}$ *inside the scope* of another $\lim\limits_{n\to\cdots}$ that tries to bind the same variable.

Comment: I don't think the binding is the issue. I think the issue is that the inner fraction is undefined.

Comment: @quasi: That in itself just makes the whole thing _undefined_. Being _nonsense_ is worse than that, and is caused by the scope confusion.

Comment: I don't see scope as the issue. For example, I would regard
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\left(
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\large{\frac{1}{n}}}
\right)
$$
as meaning the same as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (0)
$$
which of course equals $0$.

Comment: On the other hand, while an expression can be undefined, I don't regard it as meaningful to deliberately _form_ an expression with a part that's clearly undefined.

Answer (score -2):

I found it confusing
After not paying enough attention i leaped a wrong conclusion
and were going to apply a limit theorem to the inside expression
$\frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}{n}}{\lim_{n\to \infty}{n^2}}$ till poster
quasi reminded me that this is impossible since both sequences in the nominator
and denominator diverge to infinity respectivly.

The only possible meaning you might get would be arriving at an undefined expression $\frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}n}{\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$  as quasi explained in the comments to this post.

Remark:I changed the content of this post after the comments and left the irrelevant parts of the original version that were not  directly adressing the 
question out.

Comment: But how does your answer address the actual limit expression in the OP's question?

Comment: @quasi Ok thanks for your comments i have noticed that i confused the matter
and arrived at wrong conclusions My Apologies

Comment: The expression
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}
\frac{n}{n^2}
$$
evaluates to $0$, whereas the expression
$$
\frac
{\lim_{n\to \infty} n}
{\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2}
$$
does not evaluate to $0$, but rather, evaluates to $\infty/\infty$, which is undefined.

Comment: Ok you are right  i forgot to consider it,it was a blunder on my side

Comment: There's no instance of ${\large{\frac{n}{n^2}}}$ or anything equivalent to it in the OP's limit expression.

Comment: Yes thanks i misread and confused the OP's question ,sorry